# Tinkerpop traversal to string

Tags: java, gremlin, tinkerpop, amazon-neptune

Is it possible to get from a traversal a gremlin request ready to use ? As JPA do with the log in debug level. For tinkerpop the debug give the `traversal.toString()` which is time consuming to transform in a request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can translate a traversal back into a textual form using the GroovyTranslator class from Apache TinkerPop.

If you had a traversal defined as follows

```
 Traversal t = 
      g.V().has("airport","region","US-TX").
            local(values("code","city").
            fold());
```

You can convert that back to a text string using

```
String query;
query = GroovyTranslator.of("g").
        translate(t.asAdmin().getBytecode());
    
System.out.println("\nResults from GroovyTranslator on a traversal");
System.out.println(query);
```

There are further examples here:

https://github.com/krlawrence/graph/blob/master/sample-code/RemoteWriteText.java